# AngularJS - Pass Error from Service to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Service.js**

```
    myService.serviceName = function (userId) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/someUrl'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('Service errorCallback');
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
```

**Controller.js**

```
myService.ControllerName(data.id)
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            //do processing here
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            toaster.pop({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Display Error Message!'
            });
        });
```

In service, we are getting error status code in console viz `-1`, `-2` and based on that code we are displaying custom error message to the user.

- How do I pass error (message/code) from service to controller ?

Comment: Aren't you getting same status code in error block of service call in controller?

Comment: You don't need use `.catch(function (error) {
                throw error;
            })`, because `.catch(function (error) {
                toaster.pop({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Display Error Message!'
                });
            })` can catch all http errors.

Comment: What I see in console when call is made from service to controller
`Service - statusCode="-1"
Controller - Error: data is undefined` Probably, in controller it goes into `then` instead of `catch`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to accept callbacks from the Controller.

```
myService.serviceName = function (userId) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/someUrl'
    })
};
```

And in your Controller:

```
myService.serviceName(123).then(function(response) {
    // Do the processing.
}, function(error) {
    // Check the error and change the UI accordingly. 
});
```

If you need to make the processing within the service, you might want to use the $q service. In this case, you would need to inject it into your Service.

```
myService.serviceName = function (userId) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function (response) {
        // Do the processing.
        defer.resolve(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

In your controller:

```
myService.serviceName(123).then(function(response) {
    // Indicate that everything went OK.
}, function(error) {
    // Check the error and change the UI accordingly.
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question by adding callback functions for success and error. Executing the new code, it first goes into `Service successCallback` and then `Controller errorCallback` and says `response is not defined` I am not sure what I am missing here. Pls guide.

Comment: That's because you're trying to attach callbacks twice for $http. Try using my snippet with $q.

Comment: Updated my code using $q. It says `Error: $q is not defined`. Guess `$q dependency` should be added in my service code

Comment: Sure, I wrote that you should inject $q before using it.

Comment: Gotcha. The `return defer.promise;` should be after defer.reject and not after catch block is closed. Pls validate me

Comment: The `return defer.promise` should be after $http with its async callbacks, and certainly not within them. Because `return defer.promise` runs BEFORE the callbaks given to $http.then with `defer.reject` or `defer.resolve`.

Comment: is this okay `myService.serviceName = function (userId) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/someUrl'
    }).then(function (response) {
        
  // Do the processing.
  return response.data;
        defer.resolve(response);
  
    }).catch(function (error) {
 
        defer.reject(error);
  return defer.promise;
    });
};`

Comment: No, `return defer.promise;` should be the very last statement. Check my example once again.

Answer (score 0):

You could add functionality to add callbacks to the service.

This way the controller can register its own callback method to the service. Which in its turn will call said callback method when the error occurs. Notifying the controller of the occurred error and desired message.

Comment: Could you please post snippet in relation to the above posted code ?

Comment: Does EternalLight his answer help you out? Otherwise I'll add a snippet.